# Issues importing RiTa using command line environment

Tags: java, import, compilation, command-line-interface

I'm having an issue importing [RiTa](http://rednoise.org/rita/index.php) into a Java program. I'm using the command line on Ubuntu 17.10.

```
rita.jar  rita.support.jar  test.class  test.java
john@COMPUTER:~/CS/249/bored$ jar tvf rita.jar 
     0 Mon Jul 16 23:13:02 EDT 2018 META-INF/
   104 Mon Jul 16 23:13:00 EDT 2018 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  7684 Mon Jul 16 23:13:00 EDT 2018 JWNLResource_en.properties
   561 Mon Jul 16 23:13:00 EDT 2018 PrincetonResource_en.properties
     0 Mon Jul 16 23:13:00 EDT 2018 rita/
 17289 Mon Jul 16 23:12:42 EDT 2018 rita/RiGrammar.class
 19439 Mon Jul 16 23:12:42 EDT 2018 rita/RiLexicon.class
 25441 Mon Jul 16 23:12:42 EDT 2018 rita/RiMarkov.class
 18392 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiString.class
   713 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiTa$1.class
   670 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiTa$RiTaLoaderSource.class
 44101 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiTa.class
  3146 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiTaEvent.class
   706 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiTaException.class
   860 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiText$1.class
 54832 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiText.class
  1243 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018     rita/RiWordNet$ComparableIndexWord.class
 50132 Mon Jul 16 23:12:44 EDT 2018 rita/RiWordNet.class
   603 Mon Jul 16 23:13:00 EDT 2018 rita/open.gif
1114374 Mon Jul 16 23:13:00 EDT 2018 rita/rita_dict.js
300561 Mon Jul 16 23:13:00 EDT 2018 rita/rita_lts.js
   388 Mon Jul 16 23:13:00 EDT 2018 rita/save.gif
john@COMPUTER:~/CS/249/bored$ javac -cp "./*" test.java 
john@COMPUTER:~/CS/249/bored$ java test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     rita/RiString
at test.main(test.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rita.RiString
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

As you can see, `rita.jar` does seem to contain `RiString`. `test.java` just tries to import `rita.*` and then make a `RiString`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out I just didn't know how to run it properly. 
`java -cp ".:./*" test`